# Identify the problems in this Verilog snippet

Tags: verilog

I think that the code below is wrong because it uses blocking (=) instead of non-blocking (<=) assignments but since there is only one statement in the always block is this an issue?

Also, it is sensitive to `op` but it also updates `op` within the always block, will this create some sort of loop condition?

Are there other problems with it?

```
always @ (a or op)
begin
  op = a + b;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using (reading) b and it is **not** in the sensitivity list.

`op` should not be in the sensitivity list but it does not hurt.

It is strongly recommended to use always @( *) in these cases.

The assignment is correct and should be blocking.